# How to attach OpenTelemetry span to default span in Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, open-telemetry

I have a HTTP endpoint in Google Functions named `process_me`:

```py
def process(request: Request) -> str:
  return process_message(request)
```

which generates `/process_me` traces in GCP.
Now to trace a bit further I add OpenTelemetry:

```py
def process(request: Request) -> str:
  with TRACER.start_as_current_span("process_message") as span:
    return process_message(request)
```

which in turn leads to traces no longer starting with `/process_me`. Instead they are named/have URL `process_message`.
Everything that is traced underneath the span is properly attached to `process_message`, though.

So I wonder how do I add Span `process_message` to Span `/process_me` (instead of replacing it)?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that `/process_me` is the trace entry of the Loadbalancer. So I want this to go beyond Network Services.

The best I could come up with was:

````py
def _build_trace_links(headers: EnvironHeaders) -> List[Link]:
    """
    Tries to extract GCP trace context from headers.
    Example header would be:
    ```
    X-Cloud-Trace-Context: TRACE_ID/SPAN_ID;o=TRACE_TRUE
    ```
    """
    trace_header: str = headers.get("X-Cloud-Trace-Context", "")
    if not trace_header:
        return []
    ids, opts = trace_header.split(";", 1)[0]
    b = opts.split("=", 1)[1]
    if b.upper() != "TRACE_TRUE":
        return []

    trace_id, span_id = ids.split("/", 1)

    parent_context = SpanContext(
        trace_id=int(trace_id, 16),
        span_id=int(span_id),
        is_remote=True,
    )

    return [Link(context=parent_context)]
````

This way you can extract the parent and add at least a link to `process_message`.

Answer (score 0):

I could see you found some relevant information already but it is not parent-child relationship in the trace and you are doing your own parsing and linking. I believe what you need here is the propagator that does all the work for you. I am not really super familiar with Google Cloud Function but I think this should help.

Install the propagator

```sh
python -m pip install opentelemetry-propagator-gcp
```

And the set the global text map propagator

```py
...
from opentelemetry.propagate import set_global_textmap
from opentelemetry.propagators.cloud_trace_propagator import CloudTraceFormatPropagator
...

set_global_textmap(CloudTraceFormatPropagator())

...
```